# filling data in multidimensional numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am really not familiar to python so sorry if my question is too simple. Suppose I had a 2d `numpy` array

```
size = width, height
array = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.uint8)
```

Suppose I have a 1d array of data `data_array` and I want to put the data in the `array` variable

```
for i in range(0,width-1):
    for j in range(0,height-1):
       array.append(data_array[i*rows+cols])
```

But, it seems not possible to use append for multidimensional bumpy arrays

Comment: You shouldn't use append on numpy arrays at all, because they are static.

Comment: Filling and appending are two different operations. Use a sample case and with it explain what you are looking for?

Comment: @Divakar I edited my post. In fact, as the loop suggests, I have data stored in a 1d array (`data_array`), I want to put each of the elements of the `data_array` in the `numpy` array

Comment: Post a [`mcve`](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my previous comments, I meant if you could post sample inputs, i.e. `array` and `data_array` with sample numerical data but minimal in size and representative of your actual use case. Then, add the expected output with those sample data. All in this short, let's call it mcve :)

Answer (score 1):

You can reshape your 1D array with

```
array=data_array.reshape(width, height)
```

if the total size is the same

Comment: thank you and what is the best way to affect data of this array into the zero numpy array ?

Comment: I think what you want to do is, inside your loop:

           array[i,j]=(data_array[i*rows+cols])

but just by doing array=data_array.reshape(width, height)
it will all be done automatically without need for loops

Answer (score 0):

If you really need to build a 2d array element by element here's the basic way to do it:

```
size=3,4
A=np.zeros(size,int)
for i in range(size[0]):
   for j in range(size[1]):
      A[i,j] = i*4 + j   # assign elements, don't append
```

producing

array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])

But with `reshape` I can do the same, and faster

```
In [190]: x=np.arange(12)

In [191]: x
Out[191]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 11])

In [192]: x.reshape(3,4)   # may want to add a .copy()
Out[192]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Another common way of building an array is to append to a list, and turn that into an array at the end of the loops.

```
In [193]: alist=[]    
In [195]: for i in range(3):
   .....:     ll = []
   .....:     for j in range(4):
   .....:         ll.append(i*4+j)
   .....:     alist.append(ll)
   .....:     

In [196]: alist
Out[196]: [[0, 1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11]]

In [197]: np.array(alist)
Out[197]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11]])
```

Or in compact list comprehension form:

```
np.array([[i*4+j for j in range(4)] for i in range(3)])
```

This could be faster if I could perform that `j` iteration as an array

```
for i in range(3):
    alist.append(i*4+np.arange(4))
```

Better yet if we do both dimensions this way

```
np.arange(3)[:,None]*4 + np.arange(4)
```

This uses 'broadcasting' to create an outer produce of 2 arrays

```
In [209]: np.arange(3)*4, np.arange(4)
Out[209]: (array([0, 4, 8]), array([0, 1, 2, 3]))
```

Another way to fill the array is to assign to a 'flat' version:

```
A.flat[:]=np.arange(1,13)
```